# Spring Boot & Spring Batch auto wiring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm trying to get me head around Spring Boot's auto wiring for Spring Batch.  In the example in the Spring docs, there are a number of parameters being passed in the constructor to some beans.

The example works, but if I try to create another job using the identical configuration (naming it `importUserJob2`), I get a non-unique bean exception - the error reports there are 2 step beans.

```
@Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step s1, JobExecutionListener listener) {
        return jobs.get("importUserJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .flow(s1)
                .end()
                .build();
    }
```

What does the constructor here mean when used with parameters (I can't see where these parameters are supplied) and where are these beans being created?  How do I create 2 jobs?

EDIT: here are the 2 jobs, 2 steps and the exception I get.

```
@Bean
public Job helloJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step s1, JobExecutionListener listener) {
    return jobs.get("helloJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener)
            .flow(s1)
            .end()
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .tasklet(helloTasklet())
            .build();
}


@Bean
public Job otherJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step s1, JobExecutionListener listener) {
    return jobs.get("otherJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener)
            .flow(s1)
            .end()
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step step2(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader<MyReadItem> reader,
                        ItemWriter< MyReadItem > writer) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
            .< MyReadItem, MyReadItem > chunk(10)
            .reader(reader)
            .writer(writer)
            .build();
}
```

And the exception:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.core.Step] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: step1,step2
```

What creates `Step s1`?  Am I right in thinking that Spring just looks for any bean that is the correct type (`Step`), but there are 2 found?  Do I need to qualify the steps when they're created to ensure the correct one is injected??

Comment: What constructor are you referring to?  The only constructor in the code snip above is `new RuIdIncrementer()`...and I doubt that's your issue.

Comment: Sorry, Michael, poor choice of words on my part - I'm referring to the method above that creates the bean (importUserJob above).

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that method.  What `Step` bean definitions do you have in your configuration?

Comment: That method's fine, but if I repeat the definition and call the second method "importUserJob2", with a different step, then I get the non-unique exception I described. Where is s1 being defined? The step definition is as per the Spring docs example.

Comment: I've added both jobs & steps and the exception I get to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both your job definitions methods, you are using "Step s1" as a parameter. Since "s1" is not a name of a bean, spring will try to autowire by type. However, it will find two steps ("step1" and "step2") in the context. I guess, that's the reason for your exception. 
You could either change the names in your parameter, or call directly the method in your definitions:

```
@Bean
public Job otherJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, JobExecutionListener listener) {
    return jobs.get("otherJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener)
            .flow(step2())
            .end()
            .build();
}
```

Spring takes care, that it not simply calls the step2 method, but instead provides a real spring-bean.